# When using a SQL Transaction, how long can I keep it open without causing a problem

Tags: sql-server

I have an Web App hosted on Azure.  It has a complicated signup form allowing users to rent lockers, add spouse memberships etc.  I don't want to add records to the database until EVERYTHING on that page is completed and checks out.  I am using a SQL Transaction so that I can add records to various tables and then roll them back if the user does not complete the entries properly, or simply exits the page.  I don't want a bunch of orphaned records in my DB.  All of the records that will eventually be added reference each other by the identity field on each table.  So, if I don't add records to a table, I don't get an identity returned to reference in other tables.

At the start of the page, I open a SQL connection and associate it with a Transaction and I hold the transaction open until the end of the process.  If all is well, I commit the transaction, send out emails etc.

I know best practice is to open and close a SQL connection as quickly as possible.  I don't know of any other way to operate this page without opening a SQL connection and transaction and holding it open until the end of the process.

If I should not be doing it this way, how do others do it?

Comment: I would use some type of app or browser state to track this and then submit the completed request at the end (session storage or local storage are options). Another option is to persist the state server side but not in the final tables, you could use a different set of tables just for this or a different database or storage all together (like a no-sql solution or even a flat file). Then you won't pollute the final tables and you do not need a long held transaction which can lock records for other requests and cause performance issues, race conditions, and other problems later.

Comment: Store the information to be submitted in variables, then when the user clicks Complete/Save then you save it all at once in a transaction. Do not hold a transaction for any significant length of time (more than a few seconds, preferably shorter), it can cause serious blocking issues. If you can open and commit the transaction all server-side (in a stored procedure) that's even better

Comment: Using transactions like this with a web application is very problematic. If the user doesn't finish, the transaction just sits there idle until the connection is released which can be a really long time.

Comment: Everyone is saying about the same thing.  you should "collect ALL your information".. then "code up" your changes to your dbContext and save them.  You should never "open TRANS. / wait for user input / commit TRAN".  that is a horrible idea.  See https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-transactions-in-entity-framework-core   But this article assumes you have collected all the information beforehand.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.  This will require a re-write of the page.  But...I think it will be worth the effort.  I'm thinking maybe I create "memory tables" on the server and save them as session variables.  Then commit to the tables at the end.  I am using SQL Stored Procedures so the actual post of the page at the end will take mere seconds.  I'm really glad you are all on board with the fact that what I am doing is horrible.  It makes me feel like this time investment will be worth while.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two questions here, one about how would I do it, and the other about the limits of the DB. Starting with the second, the timeout of a transaction depends on your connection string timeout. So if the connection is still alive, you can complete the commit or do the rollback.

about how to do it, I'd not do it that way. Linking a database critical lock process to user interaction is a really bad approach. You put the performance in your user's hands and also, you're assuming goog intentional clients, but you'll also have bad guys.

I'd store it locally in the web browser the information and if the process is complete, then send the information to the DB to commit it. So the final "POST" would create all the items, which is going to also take some time.

Another option if you want to keep it server side, a Redis server to cache the information and then, "move it" into the DB when the process is finished.